# Show only news for today?

Tags: python, pandas

I am extracting the news for this site however, I only want to get “todays news”  and if there is not any news for today, just print “No news today” nothing else
Can any one help please.

````
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 20)

# Input
symbol = input('Enter a ticker: ')
print ('Getting data for ' + symbol + '...\n')

# Set up scraper
url = ("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=" + symbol.lower())
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
html = soup(webpage, "html.parser")

#News table
def get_news():
    try:
        # Find news table
        news = pd.read_html(str(html), attrs = {'class': 'fullview-news-outer'})[0]
        links = []
        for a in html.find_all('a', class_="tab-link-news"):
            links.append(a['href'])
        
        # Clean up news dataframe
        news.columns = ['Date', 'News Headline']
        news['Article Link'] = links
        news = news.set_index('Date')
        return news

    except Exception as e:
        return e

#Print
print ('\nRecent News: ')
print(get_news()```
````

Comment: If you have your date in pandas datetime, you can compare it with today's date : `df[df['Date'] == pd.Timestamp.today().normalize()` will be your dataframe with only today news

Comment: Would you mind showing me how ... I tried that already